# Speed Up Matrix Multiplication with OpenMP and Block Method: Can I Do Better?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp, matrix-multiplication

This is the code I wrote:

```
#include <omp.h>
void matrix_multi(int c[][TSIZE], int a[][TSIZE], int b[][TSIZE])
{
   int B=8;

  int i, j, k,i1,j1,k1;
#pragma omp parallel for private(i,j,k,i1,j1,k1) schedule(auto) collapse(3)
  for (i=0; i<TSIZE; i+=B)
    for (j=0; j<TSIZE; j+=B)
      for (k=0; k<TSIZE; k+=B)
        for (i1=i;i1<i+B;i1++)
          for (j1=j;j1<j+B;j1++)
            {
              int sum=0;
              for (k1=k;k1<k+B;k1++)
                {
                  sum+=a[i1][k1]*b[k1][j1];
                }
              c[i1][j1]+=sum;
            }

}
```

My question is: Can I get a better performance with some further manipulation on three inner loops?

Comment: Have you measured what performance you get? For matrix multiplication you can compare against the theoretical peak performance.

Comment: I'm not convinced this code is correct: the `collapse(3)` directive parallelises over the 3 indexes `i`, `j` and `k`. This means that you are guaranteed that no identical `i,j,k` triplets will be handled by two different threads. However, you can very well have the same `i,j` pair with a different `k` for two threads. And this will lead to a race condition into updating `c[i1][j1]`...

Comment: [This particular course video](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-172-performance-engineering-of-software-systems-fall-2010/video-lectures/lecture-1-matrix-multiply-a-case-study/) is entirely dedicated to improving the speed of Matrix Multiplication.

Comment: I strongly suggest you this stackExchange, specialised in these cases: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Linear algebra is one of the most common operations computers perform. In games and graphics libraries it is THE most common operation. It has been studied and optimized heavily, with entire research groups dedicated to it.

If you care about speed, you should be performing matrix multiplication with a [BLAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms) library. Some of the things that a BLAS library will optimize for:

- minimize cache-misses by performing the matrix multiplication in blocks rather than looping over the entire matrix
- optimize the block size for the cache-size of the computer
- if the computer/CPU has multiple cache levels, use multiple optimized block size levels
- use [SIMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) instructions if available on the CPU

Note that parallelization is not on the list. This is because in today's computers memory access is slower than the CPU. You will see *worse* performance with openmp due to the overhead of context switching.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are far away from fully optimized. Have you tried loop unroll, loop inversion, etc.?

You could refer to the following link for a step by step optimization on matrix multiplication.

http://wiki.cs.utexas.edu/rvdg/HowToOptimizeGemm/

Comment: I studied this for a day and have done lots of experiments. Unfortunately I think it is hard(or out of my ability) to exploit openMP int this method. It performs a little bit worse than the code with openMP.

Comment: @HuanmingSong The link is optimizing single thread GEMM. With an optimized single thread GEMM, you could then use OpenMP to improve performance on multi-core CPUs.